# Django: Get objects for which ForeignKey does not exist

Tags: django

Given:

```
class A(models.Model):
   ...

class B(models.Model):
   ...

class C(models.Model):
    a  = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b  = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

For a fixed **b** of class **B**, I would like to retrieve all those Objects **a** from **A**, for which there is no entry **(a,b)** in **C**.

I am failing to come up with a correct filter to achieve this.

Comment: Start with finding the SQL for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with class `A`, since that's the type of object you ultimately want. You'll either want to `filter` those or `exclude` them. We could try to filter for the objects that don't have a matching entry, but you know what? It'll be easier to exclude the ones that *do* have a match.

Assuming class `A` has a related field of `c` for the `C.a` foreign key...

```
A.objects.exclude(c__b=b)
```